# What are the things to consider before extending RAM of desktop PC?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have *hp elitedesk 800 g1* desktop PC. It has two RAM slots occupied out of four available RAM slots. Details are as below.

> First slot: Type - DDR3 Size, 4096 MBytes, Manufacturer   Samsung
>
> Second slot: Type - DDR3 Size,    4096 MBytes, Manufacturer   Samsung

I want to extend total RAM to 16 GB.
Should I consider context described above while extending it? Some of the considerations are mentioned below.

- Same Manufacturer as of first two slots
- One 8GB RAM or matching capacity i.e two 4GB RAM

What are the other things to consider before extending RAM of desktop PC?

Comment: The first thing to consider is whether or not you really need it. What indications do you have that you're short on RAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For best compatibility it is preferred to get memory with similar timings, specifically the CAS Latency (CL) at the speed of your current modules. If you have DDR3-1600 CL9 then it is best to get a module that is the same, but a module that is faster, as in higher speed (1800) and lower CL (7 or 8), *should* work at the speed of your current modules.

You don't need to care about getting modules from the same manufacturer.

You can get more exact information on your modules using the program [CPU-z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), the information for your memory will be on the SPD tab.

The other thing to consider is that you should prefer getting pairs of modules over a single module. In this case you should get the 2 x 4GB rather than 1 x 8GB. This is because the two modules will allow your computer to work in what is known as dual-channel mode which can give a performance boost for certain memory intensive tasks.

Comment: This is a great answer, but you should also always check the manufacturer's documentation  for the supported memory. For this motherboard, you can't use "DIMMs constructed with x4 SDRAM are not
supported". There are a number of other stipulations as well, see the manual here: http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/manualsResults?sp4ts.oid=5387475&ac.admitted=1483422631139.1123376534.199480143

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider 2 things;

**1. Can your hardware support it?**

As other answers have pointed out, you want to look at the speed of the ram, along with the voltage requirements (unlikely to be a problem but worth being aware of) and also the maximum ram your motherboard will support (in both how many sticks, and of what size in Gb).

**2. Can your software support it?**

Windows 32bit only supports upto 4Gb of ram, and while I presume you are running 64bit, it's always worth checking via the my computer dialog (Right click my computer, properties, windows version). It wouldn't be the first time I've heard of someone being sold a system with more ram than it can ever make use of!

For buying ram I like to use [crucial.com](http://crucial.com) as they can do a system scan which will guarantee the ram you get, however there is a great many suppliers out there.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can put in a second matched pair of differing manufacturer and have it work just fine as long as you stay within maximum allowed memory your BIOS allows.

You do not typically need to match the first pair in any way in a dual channel configuration if you install the second pair in the proper slots.  There are always the anomalies though.